# SSRS report with drop down list when exported to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that goes out to a team with some of the fields blank. They fill out the blanks for each record and send the report elsewhere. We have a requirement for a new 'blank' field for the users to fill out, but it has been requested that this be a drop down since there are only certain valid values here. I'm hoping that SSRS has the capability to add a dropdown (that will export properly to Excel), but my preliminary googling seems to indicate that what I'm looking for isn't possible. Hopefully someone out there can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a straight forward way to do it, but thought about rendering as HTML. On the [W3 Schools website](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), you can see HTML code for a drop-down list.

Go into your text box, enter an expression that contains HTML code like the exmple on W3:

```
="<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>

 </body>
 </html>"
```

Click ok. Then you need to go to the placeholder properties. In the placeholder properties you can choose to "Render as HTML."

I did a little testing and it looks like Excel will automatically read the HTML. Hopefully this works for you

Comment: This answer should note that [not all HTML tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) are supported in SSRS, but if the report is not intended for use except when exported to Excel, this should work.

Comment: I tried using this example, but it just renders all of the options as a single string, so instead of a dropdown, the cell says VolvoSaabOpelAudi.

Comment: @JoshBlade, is that after you export to Excel?

Comment: @BJones, Both before and after. I also tried deploying to the Reporting server to make sure it wasn't just a quirk of the VS tools.

Comment: @JoshBlade, Maybe you need to un-check the "Render as HTML" so that it can export the raw HTML. Then when you export to Excel it might read it correctly.

Comment: @BJones, My options are "None - Plain Text Only" and "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles". When I leave it plain text, it shows all of the tags. Excel doesn't convert it either. It's still just shows plain text. I also tried just the <select> portion without the html and body. It renders the same. I did notice that <select> and <option> are not in the link that Steve-o169 posted of supported tags, so maybe it's just not possible. Looks like it's really only formatting tags that work. I also tried just using <li>, but it just shows all items as a list (as expected).

Comment: Yeah, it's not supported by SSRS, but should work with Excel. You can copy/paste that HTML code into an Excel cell and it gives you a drop-down. The trick is how to do that with an export. I don't have my visual studio with me right now. I'll have to test it out later.

Comment: @BJones Could you please share the trick you did to export SSRS Report for generic Excel?